# What is use of trigger , Can anyone explain with an example that where we should use?

Tags: java, sql, database

I am beginner in sql, please explain with an example. As I know that how to create a simple trigger, but I don't have any real example where exactly we should use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Database triggers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031/database-triggers)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trigger is used to automatically act (i.e., apply your logic) when a certain action is performed. A simple example could be if you have a column holding the last modification date - on every insert on update to that table, you'd want that column to be updated to the current timestamp, regardless of how it was done, or by which application.